# selecting price depending on day number and time

Tags: mysql

I have in my mysql database table data like

```
    id  day from        to          category_id size_id price
____________________________________________________________________
    1   1   NULL        NULL        12          18      4.90    
    5   1   11:30:00    14:00:00    12          18      3.00
```

where day represent dayofweek `1=Monday, 2=Tuesday,....`

If a user purchases the product on `Monday` the products under `category: 12 and of size_id:18` should cost him `$ 4.90` but if purchases `currenttime()` between `11:30 to 14:00` it should cost him `$ 3.00`

I need a query which only returns the price depending on `day number` and `currenttime`

I have no idea if to use `case statement` ment of `Exists` if it is possible to write a single query or 2.

Comment: To avoid special processing for "from NULL to NULL" what if you change it to "from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00". Also, can there be nested time periods like "from 11:30:00 to 14:00:00" and "from 12:00:00 to 13:45:00" or overlapping periods like "from 11:30:00 to 14:00:00" and "from 12:00:00 to 17:45:00" ?

Comment: There are no overlapping periods, and I can change the NULL value of from and to also.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should work:

```
SELECT IFNULL(
    (SELECT price FROM `table1` WHERE `category_id` = @id AND `size_id` = @size_id AND `from` >= curtime() AND to < curtime() LIMIT 1), 
    (SELECT price FROM `table1` WHERE `category_id` = @id AND `size_id` = @size_id AND `from` IS NULL AND `to` IS NULL LIMIT 1) AS `Price`
```